# BlackBerry InputStream to String conversion

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How do I convert an InputStream to a String on a BlackBerry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would store the data from the inputStream in a StringBuffer. The code would look like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int readIn = 0;
while((readIn = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
     String temp = new String(buffer, 0, readIn);
     sb.append(temp);  
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 13):

How about this for minimal code:

```
String str = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Is there a non-Blackberry solution?

Comment: yes, look at the accepted answer for this question from Jonathan - that doesn't use any BlackBerry-specific APIs

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan's approach assumes your bytes represent a String in default BlackBerry encoding (ISO-8859-1). However most modern apps are multy-languaged, so the best encoding to support is UTF-8. To respect a set encoding you may use smth like this:

```
/**
 * Constructs a String using the data read from the passed InputStream.
 * Data is read using a 1024-chars buffer. Each char is created using the passed 
 * encoding from one or more bytes.
 * 
 * <p>If passed encoding is null, then the default BlackBerry encoding (ISO-8859-1) is used.</p>
 * 
 * BlackBerry platform supports the following character encodings:
 * <ul>
 * <li>"ISO-8859-1"</li>
 * <li>"UTF-8"</li>
 * <li>"UTF-16BE"</li>
 * <li>"UTF-16LE"</li>
 * <li>"US-ASCII"</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param in - InputStream to read data from.
 * @param encoding - String representing the desired character encoding, can be null.
 * @return String created using the char data read from the passed InputStream.
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs.
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if encoding is not supported.
 */
public static String getStringFromStream(InputStream in, String encoding) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader reader;
    if (encoding == null) {
        reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    } else {
        reader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);            
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    final char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = reader.read(buf)) > 0) {
        sb.append(buf, 0, len);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```